# How do you do change of variables for triple integrals?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am evaluating the function over the following bounds.$$\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}z\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

I'm not sure how to combine triple integrals and change of variables. Can someone run me through the steps for this problem?

thanks

Comment: What new variables are you trying to change to? In 3D, this is usually done with a Jacobian

Comment: see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx)

Comment: @JohnDoe i'm trying to change it to spherical coordinates.

Comment: @pranavB23 that didn't really help. We are not given any transformation and i'm just not sure how to rewrite the bounds of integration in terms of rowe, phi, and theta

Comment: @Marc92 see Lances answer

Comment: @pranavB23 Lance's answer does not address the question of the bounds of integration

Comment: You should have asked a better question.  Only as people are trying to help you, is it becoming apparent what your question is.  You should have asked something like, "I am trying to convert this integral to spherical coordinates.  I know the integral is over the first octant, but I don't know how to find the limits of integration in terms of $r, \theta,\phi.$"  Also, you should learn to format your questions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @saulspatz my apologies. does anyone know how to find the limits of integration?

Comment: @Marc92 I'm posting an answer.  I'm  slow typist, so it will take me a little while.  No apologies necessary.  I'm trying to help you do better next time.

Comment: @saulspatz thank you saulspatz. I have found the answer using regular integration without changing variables, but my professor would like us to use change of variables. The answer should be 5.02655 which is 8pi/5. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Generally there are two challenges in making a change of variables for a definite integral, rewriting the integrand and rewriting the limits of integration.  The first part is often easier, or at least more straighforward, since in principle on knows how to express each old variable in terms of the new variables.  The limits of integration, on the other hand, can be quite difficult to rewrite since it may not be easy to express the region given by the old limits in terms of the new variables.  In practice one might well have to resort to breaking the region into multiple pieces.

Answer (score 2):

the bound is a globe (the one eighth in the first octant). you can change to spherical coordinates.

$x=r\cos\theta\cos\phi$

$y=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$

$z=r\sin\phi$

$\mathrm{d}V=\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z=r^2\sin\phi\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi$

Comment: thanks. edited.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean  by "the bound is a globe."  The integral is over the first octant.

Comment: I found that the integral is over the first octant. I drew out the region, but I"m not sure how to convert these bounds to spherical.

Comment: @Marc92   perhaps an [example](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/TISphericalCoords.aspx) would help you understand

Comment: @saulspatz I think Lance's point is that the bound is part of a sphere, so spherical co-ordinates are a good co-ordinate transform. I think this answer was written before OP confirmed that they already knew this in the comments

Comment: @JohnDoe My comment was also written before the OP explained what he really wanted to know.  I just thought the phrase was a bit ambiguous, and I wanted to nail it down.

Answer (score 2):

As you said in a comment to Lance's answer, the integral is taken over the first octant, since we have $x,y,z\ge0$.  The sphere has radius $2$, so we have $0\le r\le 2$.  Now $\theta$ is the angle of rotation about the $z$-axis.  It's just like $\theta$ in polar coordinates.  Since we're only in the first octant, $0\le\theta\le\frac{pi}{2}$.  Now $\phi$ is the angle between the vector and the $z-axis$.  There are a couple of different systems for defining it.  Some people restrict $0\le\theta\le \pi$.  Others restrict $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}.$  In any event, because we are only taking the hemisphere above the $xy$-plane, $\phi$ will have a range of length $\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Using the system given in Lance's answer, we will have $0\le \theta \le \frac{pi}{2}.$  (Notice that when $\theta=0, z=r\sin \theta= 0,$ and when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}, z=r\sin \theta =r.$)  Finally, the integral becomes  $$\int_0^2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{r\sin \phi}\sqrt{4-r^2cos^2\phi}r^2\sin\phi\, \mathrm d\phi\, \mathrm d\theta\, \mathrm dr
$$

Comment: i'm not sure how to integrate the inside region after converting the rectangular to spherical

Comment: That's a different question.  If you ned help doing the integral, you should ask another question.  But please check that I did the conversion correctly before you do.  I've been known to make mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^2 \left( \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \left( \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}z\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\,\mathrm dz\right) \,\mathrm dy \right)\,\mathrm dx \\[10pt]
& \text{The innermost integral is easy:} \\
& \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} z \underbrace{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}_\text{No  $z$ appears here.} \,\, \mathrm dz \\[10pt]
= {} & \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} z\,\mathrm d z \\
& \text{This can be done because the factor that} \\
& \text{was pulled out does not depend on $z$.} \\[10pt]
= {} & \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} \cdot \frac{4-x^2-y^2} 2 = \frac 1 2 (4-x^2-y^2)^{3/2}. \\[10pt]
& \text{So now we have} \\
& \frac 1 2 \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} (4-x^2-y^2)^{3/2}  \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \iint\limits_{\{\,(x,y)\,:\, x^2+y^2\,\le\,4 \, x,y\,\ge\,0 \,\}} (4-x^2-y^2) \, \mathrm d(x,y) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \underbrace{\left( \int_0^2 (4-r^2)^{3/2} r\, dr \right)}_\text{No $\theta$ appears here.} \, d\theta \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \cdot \frac \pi 2 \int_0^2 (4-r^2)^{3/2} r\,dr \quad \text{This works because no $\theta$ was in $\int_0^{\pi/2}\cdots\,d\theta$.} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac \pi 4 \int_4^0 u^{3/2} \left( \frac{-du} 2\right) = \cdots
\end{align}